# "cd" does not work in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, cd

I am wondering why `cd` does not work in shell script. It is as follows,

```
#!/bin/sh
cd test
mkdir $(date +%d-%mm-%Y)
```

When I run this, I get can't cd to test

```
cd: 2: can't cd to /test
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: What's your OS?  Do you have read permissions on the directory? I'm not sure what to say, as I've never seen this before.

Comment: where does test reside?  will you be running it from the parent directory of test?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10, yes I do have permissions in the directory

Comment: also, process substitution is a bash extension.  generally you should use the executing shell /bin/bash when you use special features like $(...)

Comment: like i mentioned in my answer, check `pwd`

Comment: Do you have environment variable CDPATH set?  If so, what to?

Comment: @Foo Bah: That's command substitution, not process substitution. It's supported by all POSIX shells. Even non-POSIX shells (some, at least) support it using backticks.

Comment: @Dennis correct, but there are flavors of sh which only support backticks

Answer (score 77):

I had the same problem.  Turned out the problem was \r\n line endings.

To fix it, do

```
tr -d "\r" < oldname.sh > newname.sh
```

From http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?s=1cadd53b369d5408c2b9d53580a32dc4&t=67836&page=2

Comment: Excellent. I had this issue when running Docker on Windows host and mounting windows folder as a directory in linux container. Adding this comment in hopes it will get indexed by search engines for people like me :)

Comment: I god damn love you, dude.

Comment: Logged into SO just to upvote this!  Thanks.

Comment: Same problem with WSL / docker. You could also open the file from Windows in Notepad++, and then do Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix (LF), then save the file.

Answer (score 18):

Not really relevant for this question. I had the same error message, however, I was using

```
cd ~/foo/bar
```

After changing this to

```
cd $HOME/foo/bar
```

it was fixed.

Comment: Hero, this fixed my issue when cd'ing in a for loop on mac

Comment: This fixed my problem. I learned "~" does not resolve to "$HOME" inside of double quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, and was very confused for a while.

It turns out I had set my `$CDPATH` environment variable, which normally allows regular `cd` commands to work as usual. However, I was running my script in non-interactive mode, as "sh" (not "bash"), where the behavior is a little different. It seems that a command like:

```
cd subdir  # works via interactive bash; not in script run via sh.
```

will work as expected in my interactive login shell, bash, even when `CDPATH` is set. However, when I run the identical command in a script (using `sh`), it failed with

```
myscript.sh: line 9: cd: subdir: No such file or directory
```

I modified it to be a relative path:

```
cd ./subdir
```

and it works! I believe the difference is in how the shell uses `CDPATH`. In one case, it searches both `CDPATH` *and* your current directory, but in the script it *only* searches `CDPATH`. This is similar to the behavior of `PATH`. If you leave `.` (the current directory) out of your `PATH`, then you have to type `./localbinary` instead of just `localbinary` to execute that file.

This is my educated guess. When I set / unset `CDPATH` it breaks / unbreaks the `cd subdir` command, and `cd ./subdir` works in all cases for me.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for absolute paths? e.g cd /dir1/dir2/dir3

Answer (score 4):

put `pwd` as the first line.  Then see if that directory has a test subdirectory.

It looks like its running from the root directory

Comment: I am running it from my home directory and yes, I do have a test sub-directory.

Comment: Your error message suggests you were running from the root directory '/'.  what is the output from `pwd` when you run it in the shell?

Comment: I cna't `cd` to the output of `pwd` just shows "no such file or directory". But if I copy/paste the output to a `cd` in the terminal it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by [Benito Ciaro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428439/11654962) is on point. I would just like to add another method that you can use to remove  `\r\n` line endings. Open the script in text-editor **Sublime** and in the menu

> Goto **View → Line Endings → Unix**

This will remove the '\r' character from your script. Don't forget to save your file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the script is being executed from, if the script is in your $PATH, then it will be based off of the current directory you gave the command from (working directory).

If this is a script being run as a cron job, it's best to use a full directory path.
Example:
    cd /home/user/test

Giving the full path will also work if the script is in your $PATH.

Comment: the current working directory of the execution will be the directory from which the script is launched, not the script's directory

Comment: That's what I said, I said it will be base off the directory of where the command was given (launched).

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it working using ""

So in your case it would be:

```
cd "test"
```

/Marcus

Answer (score 0):

`2` is the errno for "No such file or directory". Are you sure the script `test` exists in the working directory of the script?

You might want to `cd` to a *known* "good" directory first and then cd into *known* child directories of that good directory.

Comment: The working directory of the script will be the directory from which the script is launched.  to test, have a script run `pwd`

Comment: And the working directory of the script is where you'll start from when you `cd` to a directory, is it not? So if you run the script from a directory that does *not* have a `test` directory, it will fail. One solution here is to `cd` with the absolute path of `test`, or its parent (depending on the remainder of the script), allowing the script to be run from anywhere. Which is what I have already mostly stated in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right directory

Run the command bellow to known where are you

```
pwd
```

Shell scripts are run inside a subshell, and each subshell has its own concept of what the current directory is. The `cd` succeeds, but as soon as the subshell exits, you're back in the interactive shell and nothing ever changed there.

Try this

```
. myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in ubuntu. My command shell is:

```
$ export DIR=mydir
```

then execute a script file that contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/$DIR
```

giving output:

```
cd: 2: can't cd to ~/mydir
```

by trying many options, at the end it can only be solved like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
WORKDIR=~/$DIR
cd "$WORKDIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this but I changed the permission of the folder and it worked for me

```
chmod -R 775 ubuntu
```