# LINUX "CD" command does not work in shell script

Tags: linux

I made a shell script that I want wherever it is to go to a directory. For example if the shell is in Downloads I want it to go to Desktop create there a folder go to that folder and many other thing but CD command **does not work**.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Desktop
```

It says so:

```
setup.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to Desktop
```

I there a way to use it, please help.

Comment: So I guess that there is no `Desktop` inside `Downloads`.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918249/cd-does-not-work-in-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute path or, even better, an environment variable.

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

The 'cd' command is working great. It's telling you there's no 'Desktop' directory.

You need to provide a relative or absolute path to where that 'Desktop' directory is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
cd /home/user/some/subdir/here/Desktop
```